# Using LINQ to obtain dependencies of tasks stored in a table

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database that has a table with the following layout:

```
JobID   TaskID   DependantTaskID
--------------------------------
1000      20            19
1000      21            20
```

As you can see, it specifies for each job, and each task within that job what the dependent task identifiers are.  I wanted to write some LINQ, that given a job returned each task and the associated dependencies that I can then sort appropriately.  This is the LINQ I have:

```
var query = from t in Sys_JobDependantTasks
            where t.JobID == 1000
            select new
            {
                TaskId = t.Taskid,
                Dependencies = (from d in Sys_JobDependantTasks
                                where d.DependantTaskid == t.Taskid
                                select d.DependantTaskid).ToList()
            };

var result = query.ToList();

result.Dump();
```

... except the results are unexpected.  I get:

```
TaskId          Dependencies
----------------------------
9304            9304
                9304
```

A raw dump of the table however, says that 9304 depends on 9633.  I am pretty new to LINQ, so I was wondering if there was something obvious I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the sub query as:

```
from d in Sys_JobDependantTasks
where d.TaskId == t.DependantTaskid
select d.TaskId
```

Comment: Interestingly, this does give the right dependency back - but it gives it twice.  For example, 9304 is dependent on 9633, but I get two 9633's back for that...

Comment: +1, this works perfectly.  I needed to constrain by JobID on the inner query also, and this returned the results as expected.